# XQuery let for let output

Tags: for-loop, xquery, let

I have the following XQuery:

```
let $a := 0
for $b in (1,2,3)
let $a := $a + 1
return $a+$b
```

The result I would expect is 2,4,6

However, the result is get is 2,3,4

Why does it produce this result, i.e. why does the value of $a in the for loop stays 1?

Comment: Your two $a bindings are effectively different bindings within the same context. Variables are immutable in XQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in XQuery (and XSLT) are immutable. Therefore, once declared they cannot be reassigned.